# Iterating a While Loop with User Input

Tags: java, if-statement, random, while-loop, user-input

Firstly, thanks for reading my post and helping me out.

I'm trying to program where I define a random number, the program guesses this random number, and then, depending on whether I say the guess is too high or low, the program guesses again.

When the program guesses a number which is too high, the user is to type "lower" and then the program to only guess numbers which are lower.

Ideally, the program would consider the results of all previous choice. So if guess #1 was too high, this should remain the upper-bound for all iterations afterwards. We don't want only the upper or lower bound changing with every iteration.

What I've tried to do with my code is reset the min and max values used to compute the random number ( ThreadLocalRandom ).

The main issue is that I cannot get the oMin and oMax values to reset. I don't understand how to get around this, sorry if this is a totally silly question.

Thanks again!

```
import java.util.Scanner;

import java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom;

public class J4AB_S11_C3 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        int oMin = 0;
        int oMax = 101;
        int randomNumber = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(oMin, oMax);
        String userReply;

        System.out.println("What's the lucky number, kiddo?");
        int correctAnswer = scanner.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Is " + randomNumber + " the right answer?");
        userReply = scanner.next();

        while ("Higher".equalsIgnoreCase(userReply)) {
            oMin = randomNumber;
        }

        while ("Lower".equalsIgnoreCase(userReply)) {
            oMax = randomNumber;
        }

        if (userReply.equalsIgnoreCase("Correct")) {
            System.out.println("We finally did it! " + correctAnswer + " was the correct answer.");
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: When do you want the oMin and oMax to be reset and what are you trying to reset them to (0 and 101)?

Comment: I want them to be reset when a guess is too high or too low. If the correct answer is 20, but the program guesses 40, I'd like 40 to be set as the new max.

Comment: ^ and I would like these changes to be preserved over time so that the scope of the guess continually becomes smaller.

Comment: I think I understand, give me a few minutes to review your code and I'll try to post a solution.

Comment: You're using 'while ("Higher".equalsIgnoreCase(userReply))' while when you should be using if.

Comment: A few things, you don't really use correctAnswer other than to show it on your final output. if the user is the one deciding if it's correct or not you could just use userReply. I don't think that's what you want.

Comment: I just wanted to thank you all again for lending me your expertise and helping me learn to program. You guys are the people who make this community incredible. Have a good weekend, all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use do-while for this, if-condition to check higher and lower. And close `scanner` after the do-while

```
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        int oMin = 0;
        int oMax = 101;
        String userReply;
        int correctAnswer;
        do {
            int randomNumber = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(oMin, oMax);
            System.out.println("What's the lucky number, kiddo?");
            correctAnswer = scanner.nextInt();

            System.out.println("Is " + randomNumber + " the right answer?");
            userReply = scanner.next();

            if ("Higher".equalsIgnoreCase(userReply)) {
                oMin = randomNumber;
            }else if ("Lower".equalsIgnoreCase(userReply)) {
                oMax = randomNumber;
            }
        } while (!userReply.equalsIgnoreCase("Correct"));

        System.out.println("We finally did it! " + correctAnswer + " was the correct answer.");

        scanner.close();
```

Comment: You should only close the Scanner if you're done with System.in for this program.

Comment: Thank you for this! It would have taken me hours to find this out, so it was 1000% worth posting here. I want to ask though - Shouldn't the initial "What's the lucky number?" and definition of the correct answer be outside the do-loop. Regardless, thanks a million times!

Answer (score 0):

I made a few edits and added a while loop, check it out. I tested it and it seems to be working.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

import java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom;

public class J4AB_S11_C3 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        int oMin = 0;
        int oMax = 101;
        int randomNumber = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(oMin, oMax);
        String userReply;

        System.out.println("What's the lucky number, kiddo?");
        int correctAnswer = scanner.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Is " + randomNumber + " the right answer?");
        userReply = scanner.next();
        while (!"Correct".equalsIgnoreCase(userReply)){
        if ("Higher".equalsIgnoreCase(userReply)) {
            oMin = randomNumber;
        }

        if ("Lower".equalsIgnoreCase(userReply)) {
            oMax = randomNumber;
        }
        randomNumber = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(oMin, oMax);
        System.out.println("Is " + randomNumber + " the right answer?");
        userReply = scanner.next();
        }
        if (userReply.equalsIgnoreCase("Correct")) {
            System.out.println("We finally did it! " + correctAnswer + " was the correct answer.");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this! It works for me as well. If I could give you an upvote I would, but I'm too new here.